# TYPO3 - Language menu is not showing on mobile version

Tags: mobile, typo3, responsive, typo3-11.x

I don’t have much experience with TYPO3 and I find it hard to find some things. The language menu is not displayed in the mobile version and I cannot find a solution.
In the browser inspector I notice that the `div` is disabled and the content is empty any suggestions?

```
<div class="topbar-mobile__button"></div>
```

I have reviewed the page and template options but I have not found options nor in the typo3 documentation.
CMS version is 11.5

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 core is not responsible for the page layout of your front end as the front end rendering has to be defined by a non-core extension.

In that extension you (or the extension author) needs to define templates for the page layout.

Nowadays it probably are FLUID templates splitted in `Layouts`, `Templates` and `Partials`. They include the HTML-Markup and use variables and some control structures to build the resulting page from the data.

I assume you used an public available extension/package like Boots-Trap-Package you need to analyze the FLUID-templates of that extension (which also may include Javascript and CSS) to identify what is displayed under which condition.
Then you can modify (**do an override in your own extension instead of modifying the extension from a public repository! otherwise you would not be able to update it.**) the given templates by copying the original files and configure your instance to prefer your versions instead of the original.